# Diameter of Cayley graphs of subgroups of $S_n$ without inverses

Tags: gr.group-theory

Babai and Seress [proved](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669805800290) that given a subgroup $G \leq S_n$ and a generating set $S$ of $G$, any permutation in $G$ can be written as a product of generators and their inverses of length $e^{(1+o(1))\sqrt{n\log n}}$. This bound is optimal since $S_n$ has an element of order $e^{(1+o(1))\sqrt{n\log n}}$.

The classical fact that every element in $S_n$ has order at most $e^{(1+o(1))\sqrt{n\log n}}$, combined with the result of Babai and Seress, shows that given a subgroup $G \leq S_n$ and a generating set $S$ of $G$, any permutation in $G$ can be written as a product of generators of length at most $e^{2(1+o(1))\sqrt{n\log n}}$.

> Can we improve the upper bound $e^{2(1+o(1))\sqrt{n\log n}}$ to $e^{(1+o(1))\sqrt{n\log n}}$?

This question has been inspired by the recent question [Automata and a kind of pumping lemma on state transition function](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/27072/automata-and-a-kind-of-pumping-lemma-on-state-transition-function).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes, we can improve the upper bound to $\mathrm{e}^{(1 + o(1))\sqrt{n\ln n}}$. It was proved in a more recent [paper](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1109557.1109648) of Babai (Corollary 2.9).